# why $2^nt_n$ is the characteristic function of a set $T_n \subset A$? Rudin RCA

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have  some confusion in Rudin RCA  Page no : $55$

> Lusin's theorem

> In the theorem of the proof  Rudin says to attach a sequence $\{s_n\}$ to $f$, as in the proof of Theorem $1.17$, and put $t_1 = s_1$ and $t_n = s_n - s_{n-1}$ for $n \geq 2$. He then concludes that $2^nt_n$ is the characteristic function of a set $T_n \subset A$

**My confusion** : Im not getting   why $2^nt_n$ is the characteristic function of a set $T_n \subset A$?

**My thinking**:Take $ s_n= \varphi \circ f$ where $\varphi_n(t)= \sum_{k=0} ^{n2^n-1} k2^{-n}\chi_{[k2^{-n} , (k+1)2^{-n} }(t)  +  n \chi_{[n ,\infty)} (t)$

$s_n=\varphi \circ f=\sum_{k=0} ^{n2^n-1} k2^{-n}\chi_{[k2^{-n} , (k+1)2^{-n} }f(t)  +  n \chi_{[n ,\infty)} f(t)$

Since it is given that  $0\le f < 1  \implies n \chi_{[n ,\infty)} f(t)=0 $

So $s_n=\varphi \circ f=\sum_{k=0} ^{n2^n-1} k2^{-n}\chi_{[k2^{-n} , (k+1)2^{-n}) }f(t)  $

and $s_{n-1}=\varphi \circ f=\sum_{k=0} ^{(n-1)2^n-2} k2^{-n-1}\chi_{[k2^{-n-1} , (k+1)2^{-n-1}) }f(t)  $

obviously,$$\left (s_n=\sum_{k=0} ^{n2^n-1} k2^{-n}\chi_{[k2^{-n} , (k+1)2^{-n}) }f(t) \right) 
- \left(s_{n-1}=\sum_{k=0} ^{(n-1)2^n-2} k2^{-n-1}\chi_{[k2^{-n-1} , (k+1)2^{-n-1}) }f(t)\right)  \neq \frac{1}{2^n}$$

Here im not getting   why $t_n= s_n - s_{n-1} = \frac{1}{2^n}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is to understand $\varphi_n$. Fix $\alpha\in[0,1)$. Then $\varphi_n(\alpha)$ is the first $n$ digits of $\alpha$ in the binary representation. More specifically, if $k_n$ is the greatest integer such that
\begin{align*}
2^{-n}k_n\leq\alpha<(k_n+1)2^{-n},
\end{align*}
Then either
\begin{align*}
0\leq\alpha-2^{-n}k_n<2^{-n-1},
\end{align*}
in which case $k_{n+1}=2k_n$ and $\varphi_n(\alpha)=\varphi_{n+1}(\alpha)$, or
\begin{align*}
2^{-n-1}\leq\alpha-2^{-n}k_n<2^{-n},
\end{align*}
in which case $k_{n+1}=2k_n+1$ and
\begin{align*}
\varphi_{n+1}(\alpha)-\varphi_{n}(\alpha)=2^{-n-1}(2k_n+1)-2^{-n}k_n=2^{-n-1}.
\end{align*}
Now given $0\leq f<1$, a value of $t_{n+1}=\varphi_{n+1}\circ f-\varphi_n\circ f$ is either $0$ or $2^{-n-1}$, so $2^{n+1}t_{n+1}$ is a characteristic funciton.