# what is the value of $s_n- s_{n-1}?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

My motivation comes from  [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4200901/why-2nt-n-is-the-characteristic-function-of-a-set-t-n-subset-a-rudin-rca) question

$$s_{n-1}=\sum_{k=0} ^{2^{n-1}-1} k2^{-n-1}\chi_{[k2^{-n-1} , (k+1)2^{-n-1}) }f(t) =\sum_{k=0} ^{2^{n-1}-1} k2^{-n-1}\chi_{\{x:k2^{-n-1} \le f(x)< (k+1)2^{-n-1}) \}}(x) $$

$$s_n=\sum_{k=0} ^{2^n-1} k2^{-n}\chi_{[k2^{-n} , (k+1)2^{-n}) }f(t) =\sum_{k=0} ^{2^n-1} k2^{-n}\chi_{\{x:k2^{-n} \le f(x)< (k+1)2^{-n}) \}}(x) $$

what is the value of  $s_n- s_{n-1}?$

My attempt  : $$s_n- s_{n-1}=\sum_{k=0} ^{2^n-1}-\sum_{k=0} ^{2^{n-1}-1}=\sum_{k=0} ^{2^n-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Your last sum simplifies easily as $$\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right) = \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} \frac12 = \frac{2^n}{2} = 2^{n - 1}.$$

Comment: ok ,i'm not sure @AryamanMaithani  I just assume that it's going to be a work

Comment: Since the dyadic intervals in step $n$ are obtained by bisecting the dyadic intervals in step $n-1$,  it is enough to consider the difference between 
$ \frac{2k}{2^n}\mathbb{1}_{(\tfrac{2k}{2^n},\tfrac{2k+1}{2^n}]}+\frac{2k+1}{2^n}\mathbb{1}_{(\tfrac{2k+1}{2^n},\frac{2(k+1)}{2^n}]}$ and
$\frac{k}{2^{n-1}}\mathbb{1}_{(\tfrac{k}{2^{n-1}},\tfrac{k+1}{2^{n-1}}]}$.